# How to skip an algorithm in latex list with \listofalgorithms?

Tags: algorithm, latex

How to **skip an algorithm in latex list** with

```
\listofalgorithms?
```

In my document I have algorithms that I do no not want to list when I used

```
\listofalgorithms
```

By analogy from answer for figure environnement, I have try

```
\caption[]{Algorithm}
```

instead

```
\caption{Algorithm}
```

It gives a line of dots and counter increassing.

I have also tried

```
\captionsetup[algorithm]{list=no}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{list=yes}
```

with "algorithms" also. it leads to an error.

Here in this code, I want to remove algorithm 2 in the list

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[lined,boxed,commentsnumbered, ruled,vlined,linesnumbered, frenchkw]{algorithm2e}    
\begin{document}    

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{I want to show this one in the list}
do something \;
\end{algorithm}
    
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{I do not want os show this one in the list}
do something else\;
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{I want to show this one in the list with number 3 not 2}
do nothing \;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre] which allows us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thank you for this advice and the link to describe minimal reproductible example. It is done, I have tested in overleaf.